# In a SectionStackSection, How can you change the position of the controls used in setControls(Canvas ...)?

Tags: smartgwt

In `SectionStackSection`, How can you change the position of the controls used in `setControls(Canvas ...)`

Currently, it is always on Right, how can you set it to Left or Center?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way this will work is to handle correctly the draw and the resize. So here is my working solution:

```
private void generateDetailsListGridHeader() {
    createControls();
    section = new SectionStackSection();
    section.setCanCollapse(false);
    section.setExpanded(true);
    section.setControls(controls);
    section.setItems(detailsListGrid);

    sectionStack = new SectionStack();
    sectionStack.setSections(section);
    sectionStack.addResizedHandler(new ResizedHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onResized(ResizedEvent event) {
            htmlFlow.setWidth(sectionStack.getWidth() >> 1);
            controls.setWidth(sectionStack.getWidth() - 10);
        }
    });
    sectionStack.addDrawHandler(new DrawHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onDraw(DrawEvent event) {
            htmlFlow.setWidth(sectionStack.getWidth() >> 1);
            controls.setWidth(sectionStack.getWidth() - 10);
        }
    });
}

private void createControls() {
    String title = "<table> <tr> <td style=\"vertical-align:middle; color:blue; font-size:15px\"> <b>Please double click a class from the left to display its instances</b> </td> </tr> </table>";
    controls = new HLayout(10);
    htmlFlow = new HTMLFlow(title);
    htmlFlow.setOverflow(Overflow.AUTO);
    DynamicForm form = new DynamicForm();
    TextItem versionSearchItem = new TextItem("version", "Version");
    form.setItems(versionSearchItem);
    controls.addMember(htmlFlow);
    controls.addMember(form);
}
```

By changing the width inside the onResized and onDraw, you can put every single control wherever you want!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a HLayout as your controls Canvas. The HLayout can have as its members the controls you wished to set at the first place, but now you can control their alignment within the HLayout and thus the SectionStackSection. Below you can see a simple example:

```
    SectionStack sectionStack = new SectionStack();
    sectionStack.setWidth(500);
    sectionStack.setHeight(200);

    SectionStackSection sectionStackSection = new SectionStackSection("Test");
    HLayout controls = new HLayout();
    controls.setWidth(sectionStack.getWidth()*8/10);
    controls.setHeight(5);

    controls.setLayoutAlign(Alignment.LEFT);
    controls.setLayoutAlign(VerticalAlignment.CENTER);

    IButton iButton = new IButton("C");
    iButton.setAutoFit(Boolean.TRUE);
    iButton.setLayoutAlign(Alignment.LEFT);

    controls.addMember(iButton);

    sectionStackSection.setControls(controls);
    sectionStack.addSection(sectionStackSection);
```

Use the HLayout's width to micro-manage where exactly your controls will appear, inside the SectionStackSection header. It is not a perfect solution, but will work in simple cases.

Comment: There is something correct in your answer. But the problem, is that you use `sectionStack.getWidth()` before `sectionStack` is drawn, thus it will return a `null` value and causes an error. This is because, I do not want to set the width of SectionStack, I want it to be automatic

Comment: It doesn't have that issue in production code, but only in the dev mode. The idea I wanted to show you was to use a Canvas, with the width big enough to allow you to use the setAling methods. Your solution below is of course more complete and handles things automatically when redrawing/resizing happens.

Comment: Yeah, don't forget widgets most of the time sit inside other widgets. It is not recommended to setWidth manually as it can create problems especially on resizes which is done automatically.